# Nhibernate with Asp.net WebForms - Session per Request

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, orm

I am using an HttpModule to open a session that span each request and it works great with lazy loading and everything.

My concern is that since I open a new session per request (and stores it in HttpContext.Current.Items) it opens a session for every request even request including request for .css files and images.
I recall reading that session creation is a pretty lightwheigt operation (dont know about transactions though) but anyway it seems unnecessary to open a session for a requests for a .css file?

Anyone got some ideas about this, is it a problem and/or am I doing something stupid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean HttpModule, not HttpHandler, right?

Comment: You are right ofcourse, the answer is edited now. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- only create the session object if the file type is .aspx or .ashx:

  ```
      switch (context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.ToLower())
      {
          case ".aspx":
          case ".ashx":
              context.Items[ContextKey] = CreateMySession();
              break;
      }
  ```
- or encapsulate session creation inside a property getter, and clean-up checks whether `session != null`

Comment: How expensive is it to begin an Nhib Transaction for every request (per aspx/ashx)? Can I have a transaction for every request or should I open them explicitly when needed?